# Dart Protobuf: CodedBufferReader was allowed to parse only 64M bytes

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers

I have a dart application retrieving certain amount of data from a (Java) HTTP server .
Things work OK until I attempt to retrieve more than 60Mb , where I get an Exception  like this:

**Note that the buffer containing the message has 73686993 bytes, but
CodedBufferReader was allowed to parse only 67108864 bytes.**

the code is:

```
try {
   final response = await http
       .post(url, headers: headers, body: body)
       .timeout(timeoutDuration);
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  
     return ResponseMessage.fromBuffer(response.bodyBytes);
   } else {
     debugPrint(
        "Error in the request: ${response.statusCode} - ${response.reasonPhrase}");
   }
 } catch (e) {
   debugPrint("Exception in the request: ${e.toString()}");
 }
```

and it raises the Exception when the length of the info is > 67108864

I think I must find the way to increase the allowed size of the protobuf buffer. But I can't find the how to do it.

I attempted to create a CodedBufferReader which accepts sizelimit as parameter:

```
protobuf.CodedBufferReader input = protobuf.CodedBufferReader(
Uint8List.fromList(response.bodyBytes),
 sizeLimit: 300 * 1024 * 1024,
); 
....
if (response.statusCode == 200) {      
     return ResponseMessage.fromBuffer(input.readBytes());
   } else {
     debugPrint(
      "Error in the request: ${response.statusCode} - ${response.reasonPhrase}");
   }
 } catch (e) {
   debugPrint("Exception in the request: ${e.toString()}");
 }
```

But in this case I got another regardless of the size of the message:
**Exception in the request: InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.**

(as a workaround , I'm sieving the data in the server side, but this is undesired)